# How to pass []string or []byte type to SplitAfterN in golang?

Tags: string, file, go

I'm reading file line by line and like to split line based on substring. But when I use SplitAfterN with read line passed, I'm facing below error,

**cannot convert 'variable' (type []string) to type string**

**where 'variable' = []string type**

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var fLine []string

    FileName := flag.String("fpath", "Default file path", "File path description ")
    flag.Parse()

    fptr, err := os.Open(*FileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    FileScanner := bufio.NewScanner(fptr)
    for FileScanner.Scan() {
        // Append each line into one buffer while reading
        fLine = append(fLine, FileScanner.Text())
        splitline := strings.SplitAfterN(fLine, "12345", 2)
        fmt.Println("Splited string = ", splitline[1])
    }
}
```

I'm expecting below line to split passed argument (fLine)
**splitline  := strings.SplitAfterN(fread, "12345", 2)**

Answer (score 1):

The (last) line you read is not `fLine`, that is a slice of all lines. The last line is returned by `FileScanner.Text()`. If you want to split the last line, either store that in a variable, or use the last element of the slice.

If you choose to store it in a variable:

```
line := FileScanner.Text()
fLine = append(fLine, line)
splitline  := strings.SplitAfterN(line, "12345", 2)
```

If you just want to use the last slice element:

```
fLine = append(fLine, FileScanner.Text())
splitline  := strings.SplitAfterN(fLine[len(fLine)-1], "12345", 2)
```

Comment: Thnx icza,
Given file has content =  
abcdedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890
abcdedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890

I'm trying to do like below,

1. Read this file content line by line and push to one buffer like below using 
 fLine = append(fLine, FileScanner.Text())

2. Once I got this first line i'm trying to split line into 2 part and save into another buffer, 2 part using below line

splitline := strings.SplitAfterN(fLine, "1234567890", 2)

But when I try to pass the read read string variable fLine, 

I've tried to typcase this fLine into string(fLine) still it gives error.

Comment: @Perry `fLine` is a slice of strings, you can't convert it to a `string` value. Do you see any `string` conversion in my proposed code?

Comment: Yes, I could do string conversion as per your proposed code.
Now, the problem is I'm not able to store all converted into single string buffer.

I've tried like below,


    line := FileScanner.Text()
    fLine = append(fLine, line)
    splitline  := strings.SplitAfterN(line, "12345", 2)

    //To save second part in new buffer
    FinalStr := append(FinalStr, splitline[1])


When i try to print this FinalStr, this has empty string.

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to convert the slice to a string, right?

This should do what you need..

So:

```
splitline := strings.SplitAfterN(strings.Join(fLine," "), "12345", 2)
```